# Print out the spelling of a 2-digit number using function and if-else statement in C (beginner)

Tags: c, function, if-statement

Hi I don't know why my code doesn't show the result that I expected. The exercise was print out the spelling of a 2-digit number using function and if-else statement in C. When I ran the code it return nothing. ( This is a beginner exercise, so I can only think of this so sorry :(( ) Can you please check where I was wrong thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Consider the second number in that 2-digit number when the first number is 1
void ten(char b)
{
    switch (b) {
        case(0): printf("ten"); break;
        case(1): printf("eleven"); break;
        case(2): printf("twelve"); break;
        case(3): printf("thirteen"); break;
        case(4): printf("fourteen"); break;
        case(5): printf("fifthteen"); break;
        case(6): printf("sixteen"); break;
        case(7): printf("seventeen"); break;
        case(8): printf("eighteen"); break;
        case(9): printf("nineteen"); break;
    }
}

// Consider the second number in that 2-digit number when the first number is not 1
void morethanten(char b)
{
    switch (b) {
        case(0): break;
        case(1): printf("one"); break;
        case(2): printf("two"); break;
        case(3): printf("three"); break;
        case(4): printf("four"); break;
        case(5): printf("five"); break;
        case(6): printf("six"); break;
        case(7): printf("seven"); break;
        case(8): printf("eight"); break;
        case(9): printf("nine"); break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    printf("Enter your 2-digit number: ");
    scanf("%c%c", &a, &b);

    // Consider the first number in that 2-digit number
    switch (a) {
        case(0): printf("That is not a 2-digit number"); break;
        case(1): ten(b); break;
        case(2): printf("Twenty"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(3): printf("Thirty"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(4): printf("Fourty"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(5): printf("Fifthty"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(6): printf("Sixty"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(7): printf("Seventy"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(8): printf("Eighty"); morethanten(b); break;
        case(9): printf("Ninety"); morethanten(b); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `case '4': ... /* not case 4: ... */` `'4'` is a value representing the `4` we humans are used to (it has a value that may change in different implementations (in ASCII based implemementations its value is 52)); `4` is the value 4.

Comment: Hint: Try printing `printf("%d %d", 1, '1')`. The integer `1` and the _character_ "one" (`'1'`) are two different values.

Comment: It's curious that the function `morethanten()` only prints anything for numbers that are less than 10.  That's a misnomer — the name doesn't match what the function does.

Comment: Side note: why do `ten` and `morethanten` have return types of `char` and unconditionally return `0`? Looks like those functions should be `void`, or perhaps return a `char*` instead of calling `printf`?

Comment: Add a default clause to each of your `switch` statements to print something when the value doesn't match any of the `case` statements.  Consider the merits (and demerits) of `if (scanf("%1d%1d", &a, &b) != 2) { fprintf(stderr, "You did not enter two digits\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`.

Comment: Your code might fail its tests for "fifteen", "forty" and "fifty" because you have some minor spelling mistakes (rather than due to incorrect logic).

Comment: BTW, you should _never_ ignore the result of `scanf()` as you do here.  If we didn't successfully read two values, then we should report the error and not continue to work with uninitialised values in `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case statements, you are performing a check on an integer value and not the character representation of the digit.

```
case(1): ten(b); break;
```

Your case comparison for that particular statement would be:

```
case('1'): ten(b); break;
```

Here was a quick test after correcting the case comparisons, making the test against a character.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Spelling/bin/Release$ ./Spelling 
Enter your 2-digit number: 12
twelve
```

Give that a try.  Also, you may want to reference some tutorial literature to get a better understanding on testing within the switch block.

Answer (score -1):

```html
 switch (b) {
        case 0: printf("ten"); break;
        case 1: printf("eleven"); break;
        case 2: printf("twelve"); break;
        case 3: printf("thirteen"); break;
        case 4: printf("fourteen"); break;
        case 5: printf("fifteen"); break; // Little error for name
        case 6: printf("sixteen"); break;
        case 7: printf("seventeen"); break;
        case 8: printf("eighteen"); break;
        case 9: printf("nineteen"); break;
    }

switch (a) {
          case '0': printf("That is not a 2-digit number"); break;
          case '1': ten(b); break;
          case '2': printf("Twenty "); morethanten(b); break; 
          case '3': printf("Thirty "); morethanten(b); break; 
          case '4': printf("Forty "); morethanten(b); break;
          case '5': printf("Fifty "); morethanten(b); break; 
          case '6': printf("Sixty "); morethanten(b); break; 
          case '7': printf("Seventy "); morethanten(b); break;
          case '8': printf("Eighty "); morethanten(b); break; 
          case '9': printf("Ninety "); morethanten(b); break; 
    }
```

Comment: An answer is a lot more helpful with some explanations on *why* the code is modified. And *why* it uses `case 1:` in the first switch, and `case '1':` later.